# Possible to convert tuple to array in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

How I can remove hardcoded string literals from `isValidTaskID` function and refer to `Config` keys instead?

```js
type Config = {
  markupPreprocessing?: MarkupPreprocessingSettings;
  stylesPreprocessing?: StylesPreprocessingSettings;
};

type TasksIDs = keyof ProjectBuilderRawValidConfigFromFile;

fuction isValidTaskID(taskID: string): void {
  return taskID === "markupPreprocessing" || taskID === "stylesPreprocessing";
}

// I still need the TasksIDs tuple!
type TasksAndEntryPontsSelection: Record<TasksIDs, Array<string>>;
```

Comment: I'd suggest that you probably don't need `isValidTaskID` at all. Where are you using this function? You could instead adjust those usages such that they cause the TS compiler to type check against `keyof Config`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Well, maybe I don't need this function, but I need to validate taksID which will be inputted from console. It means, TypeScript compiler will not know at advance which value will be inputted.

Comment: Ah, I see. Do you have an instance of `Config` anywhere in your code which fully specifies all possible properties? If you do, you could always do an alternative dynamic check: `function isValidTaskID(taskID: string) { return Object.keys(instance).some(key => taskID === key) }`. Otherwise, I don't think you can escape having to do those explicit checks. `Config` isn't compiled into any code, it's only used for type-checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Since typescript is just a static linter, type definitions will be erased at runtime including all the keys in your `Config` type. If you want to use it make a javascript object so it can exist at runtime

```js
type TasksIDs = keyof ProjectBuilderRawValidConfigFromFile;
const allConfigKeys: TasksIDs[] = ['markupPreprocessing', 'stylesPreprocessing']

type MarkupPreprocessingSettings = {};
type StylesPreprocessingSettings = {};
type ProjectBuilderRawValidConfigFromFile = {
    markupPreprocessing: unknown,
    stylesPreprocessing: unknown,
};

type Config = {
  markupPreprocessing?: MarkupPreprocessingSettings;
  stylesPreprocessing?: StylesPreprocessingSettings;
};

function isValidTaskID(taskID: string) {
    return allConfigKeys.includes(taskID as any);
}

console.log(isValidTaskID('a')) // false
console.log(isValidTaskID('markupPreprocessing')) // true
console.log(isValidTaskID('stylesPreprocessing')) // true

// I still need the TasksIDs tuple!
type TasksAndEntryPontsSelection = Record<TasksIDs, Array<string>>;
```

Comment: One might even consider [`return allConfigKeys.includes(taskID)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: I assume `indexOf()` is faster than `includes()` because it doesn't involve regex. But yes, `includes()` is easier to read

Comment: You assume wrong, there's no regex involved... simple identity comparison.